# Filter in collection

Tags: mongodb, doctrine-odm

My json:

```
  {
    "doc_id": "58107c7913065ff99318b268",
    "first_name": "test",
    "last_name": "test123",
    "email": "mail@account.com",
    "company": {
      "company_id": "580ab2b8ded0b2dfa56b9879",
      "name": "Test company",
      "contact_info": null,
      "location": {
        "location_id": "58094b8eded0b2dfa56b9864",
        "name": "NY",
        "formatted_address": "277 Canal St, New York, NY 10013, Stany Zjednoczone",
        "additional_options": "",
        "latitude": 50.894028,
        "longitude": 4.473816
      }
    },
    "role": "USER"
  },
```

I want to search all users where `user.company.name = 'Test company'`, or `user.company.location.name = 'NY'`

Is there any option to find it ?

This doesn't work:

`db.getCollection('User').find({"company.name": "NY"})`

also I want to do this in doctrine mongodb but didnt work. What do I wrong ?

Comment: `db.getCollection('User').find({"company.name": "NY"})` -> your company name's is "Test company", `{"company.location.name": "NY"}` would be valid for asking about location. Doctrine will consume such queries as well

Comment: no it doesn't work. I know that my company.name != "NY" but as I wrote before: `I want to search all users where user.company.name = 'Test company', or user.company.location.name = 'NY'`
but this join doesn't work

Comment: Also one important thing. Relations is made by reference, not embed documents.

Comment: Why would you expect Mongo to do JOINs for you?

Answer (score 0):

> Also one important thing. Relations is made by reference, not embed documents.

If that's the case, you're basically out of luck using simple queries. Simple queries cannot do joins. You can only query complete documents.

What you can do however is to do a multi step aggregation using the $lookup operator. It was introduced in version 3.2 so chances are you're running a compatible version.

Check out the [introductory post](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/joins-and-other-aggregation-enhancements-coming-in-mongodb-3-2-part-1-of-3-introduction) or the [relevant documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/).

Be warned though that if you have not used aggregations before, there is a bit of a learning curve to it - at least that was the case for me.